# Open whatsapp:// URI

Tags: desktop-environment

I've encountered some websites that have links starting with `whatsapp://` but there's no handler for this link.

How do I open these links automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `~/.local/share/applications/whatsapp.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=WhatsApp
Exec=google-chrome-stable https://web.whatsapp.com/
Icon=whatsapp
Type=Application
Categories=Network;InstantMessaging;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/whatsapp;
```

For firefox, you can use `Exec=firefox --new-window https://web.whatsapp.com/` instead.

Comment: Would `x-www-browser` not work just as well?